# Set up of Vimeo API

Tags: api, vimeo-api

We are trying to set up an API from Vimeo to stream content to an third part app.  We have set up the authentication key, token etc, but do not know what to do next.  Any help would be appreciated

We do not know how to link our showcase to the api to share to our client,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.